# Tell me how to install react js doc

Tags: reactjs

I would like not only to install the engine, but also to put on your local machine the documentation that you have on the official website. For the reason that I do not have permanent Internet access.

https://reactjs.org/ - > https://localhost:3000/
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reactjs.org website is also hosted on Github in this repository: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org

Clone that to your computer and follow the [Getting started guide](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org#getting-started) guide on the readme page. After running `yarn` and `yarn dev` in the project directory, the site should be visible on http://localhost:8000

Comment: I just deleted my answer! I believe this is a better answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DevDocs Offline](https://devdocs.io/offline). They have a wide range of documentation available.

Search for React and install. You will be able to access

[image]